# How to synchronize firebase data?

Tags: android, firebase

[image]

I am using`firebase` to store my data.This is how my firebase database looks like.
In my code i am trying to generate a new unique `appointment-id` on button click event. If the current `appointment-id` is 88 then it should become 89 when the user presses the button on his app, and this `appointment-id` is assigned to him as his unique `appointment-id`. The problem that I am facing is that when two or more users press the button on their app at the same time, then the same `appointment-id` is assigned to both of them.

I want my `appointment-id` to be synchronized i.e only one user can access it at a time.Is this possible ? How can I achieve it? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firebase has **transactions that will help you with incremental counters**.

```
Firebase apptRef = new Firebase("<my-firebase-app>");
apptRef.runTransaction(new Transaction.Handler() {
    @Override
    public Transaction.Result doTransaction(MutableData currentData) {
        if(currentData.getValue() == null) {
            currentData.setValue(1);
        } else {
            currentData.setValue((Long) currentData.getValue() + 1);
        }
        return Transaction.success(currentData); //we can also abort by calling Transaction.abort()
    }
    @Override
    public void onComplete(FirebaseError firebaseError, boolean committed, DataSnapshot currentData) {
        //This method will be called once with the results of the transaction.
    }
});
```

Read the [Firebase docs](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/saving-data.html#section-transactions) for more information.

Comment: So will this code now prevent two or more users to access the `appointment-id`  object concurrently?

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. Now consider a case where two users try to access `appointment-id` at the same time ,but `user1` accesses `appointment-id` 100ms before `user2` ,so now the transaction for `user1` will begin. But what about `user2`? will his transaction be in a queue or will I have to write some code to start the  transaction for `user2` as his transaction was not completed because `user1` got his turn?

Comment: It's the same situation. Each update happens transactionally. You can also test this to see if the situation works for you.

Comment: Thanks I will check and let you know.